# Правила транскрипции топонимов на «-ville» (англ. и фр.)

Tags: орфоэпия, заимствования, топонимика, транслитерация

Коллеги, подскажите пожалуйста, какое правило транслитерации английских и французских топонимов на ***-ville***? Двойное или одинарное "л" и в каких случаях?

Comment: Единого правила не существует.  Нужно рассматривать каждый конкретный случай отдельно.://litinstitut.ru/content/tolma4nonstop_goroda

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю отдельных правил в отношении именно таких топонимов, но судя по Вики (в данном случае по отзывам источник можно считать добротным) правило практической транскрипции предусматривает удвоенное **Л** во всех случаях не перед согласной:

> лл (в географических названиях л перед согласными, но всегда лл в
>   названиях валлийского происхождения; см. Валлийско-русская
>   практическая транскрипция)

Вообще общая тенденция такова, что в русском при заимствованиях имен собственных никогда не удваивается согласная, если это не предопределено произношением. Отдельные исключения возможны только по каким-то политическим мотивам (таково было написание Таллинн, которое, впрочем, быстро забылось) либо в силу традиции (Ллойд - валлийская фамилия). Судя по всему, ЛЛ в английских топонимах - такое же традиционное исключение.

В отношении французского боюсь что-то утверждать наверняка, но, помнится,  ville не слишком характерный для французской топонимики случай (нашел всего несколько городов типа Granville и Florenville). А вообще-то -ille может передаваться двумя способами.

> после гласной в конце слова или части составного наименования     [j]
>     **й**   Aureille → Орей
>
> в ряде случаев после m, v (в соответствии с произношением, иногда
>   традиционно)  [il], [ij]  **иль**     Camille → Камиль, Villeneuve →
>   Вильнёв

Похоже, что тут вернее всего будет **"-виль"**. Во всяком случае *Бугенвиль* и *Браззавиль* пишутся именно так. Других стопроцентно убедительных примеров я не вспомнил.

Comment: Спасибо большое. У меня ощущение, что американские топонимы транслитерирующая в основном с "-вилл", ориентируясь на произношение (Нашвилл, Джексонвилл).

Comment: Не могу ничего сказать по этому поводу. Не компетентен говорить, кто на кого ориентируется. Но вообще-то в русском отличить удвоенную Л от одинарной в конце слова на слух - та еще проблема.